# Journey Builder Error on Email send

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder

I am trying to send an Welcome email when new record has been added to my data extension. Journey builder is trying to send an email but throwing below error.

Error:
[image]

Email setting:

[image]

Please let me know anyone knows how to fix this.

Comment: I have Resolved this issue using mapping Email data to my custom email object field in Contact Builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have Resolved this issue by mapping Email data to my custom email object field in Contact Builder.